# When applying the same style to a component and a 'div' element, why do they behave differently?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a `component` with a selector `selector: 'app-container1'` and the following template :

```
<div style="border:2px solid blue;margin:3px;overflow:clip;display:flex">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

And a `component` with a selector `selector: '[app-container2]'` and the following template :

```
<div style="border:2px solid blue;margin:3px;overflow:clip;display:flex">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

And a simple `div` element :

```
<div style="border:2px solid blue;margin:3px;overflow:clip;display:flex">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

I then wrap them inside a container (another div) :

```
<div style="max-width: 32rem;height:32rem;background-color: red;padding-left: 5rem;">

<!-- container1 -->
  <app-container1 style="border:2px solid black;max-width: 22rem;margin:2rem;"></app-container1>

<!-- container2 -->
  <div app-container2 style="border:2px solid black;max-width: 22rem;margin:2rem;"></div>

<!-- div -->
  <div style="border:2px solid black;max-width: 22rem;margin:2rem;">
    <div style="border:2px solid blue;margin:3px;overflow: clip;display:flex">
      <button>test</button>
      <button>test</button>
      <button>test</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

I expect all three to behave exactly the same. However, while it is the case for the `div` element and `app-container2`, it is not for `app-container1`. Why ? And if possible, how can I make `app-container1` to behave the same as the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that new components created have the css property `display:inline` by default, whereas the default `display` value for a `<div>` is usually `block`.

Components who have the value `inline` take up as much space as their child components. That's why is not possible to set some `width` properties on components itself without changing the `display` property.

From your screenshot it looks like you basically want your component to always take up the whole row. You should define this component as `display:block` then.

This can be done from the parent (like you already passed styles to the component) or from the child itself like this:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

I prefer the second approach, since in this case the component itself is aware of it's styles.